# How do I install a Windows program (written in C) downloaded from GitHub?

Tags: windows-7, c

I've downloaded a dead simple Windows program from GitHub ([this](https://github.com/renatosilva/winutils) if it's relevant). I downloaded it as a ZIP file, but I can't figure out how to install it. It's written in C, I think. Do I need a compiler? (Visual Studio?) Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry, this is obviously a major noob issue I'm having. How? There's no executable file.

Comment: You probably need Windows SDK and the associated C headers to compile the program. Normally, the dependencies are mentioned and compile instructions are included in the Readme. In this case, neither is included, so you have to ask the repo owner/project author to get the relevant information.

Comment: You do need a compiler.  I would reach out to the dev and ask how to build it.  Typically Linux software, for example, provided as source includes build instructions but I don't see any on his Github.

Comment: You haven't downloaded an actual program, you have downloaded the source for the program and, yes, you do need to compile it first. Judging by the makefile in there you will need to build whatever it is in MINGW.

Comment: here is the executable https://github.com/renatosilva/winutils/releases

Comment: @barlop Turn this into a proper answer (along with an explanation)

Comment: Be glad you're not using Linux or every Linux developer would gladly spit in your face for wanting to download pre-compiled code...

Comment: heh. I've been trying to talk someone who's familiar with compiling stuff on windows to write an answer before this ages off the HNQ list ;p

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Github is primarily used by programmers to collaborate on projects. The 'Download ZIP' option downloads a copy of the source code to your computer. This *usually*<sup>1</sup> doesn't contain a copy of the compiled usable executables/binaries (ie; exe files)

[**Releases**](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), is a Github feature for shipping software to end users (who usually aren't interested in the actual coding). Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code. *This is the first place you should check for binaries*.

In your case, the [releases page](https://github.com/renatosilva/winutils/releases) offers downloads and setup files.

However, many projects won't have any releases (especially not for Windows), in which case you can do one of the following:

1. Search for binaries elsewhere on the internet. Usually search engines like [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) (or [Google](https://google.com), if you prefer) will find what you want easily. Try searching for `<application name> for Windows` or `<application name> exe`.
2. **Compile it yourself.** You need to have at least some basic knowledge of the programming language to be able to do so. Here again, search engines can be *massively* helpful. Try searching for `compile <application name> on Windows` or `MinGW compile <application name>`.

   Here I'll run through the basics of compiling utilities for Widnows:

   - Download [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). I personally favor [this](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) package because it comes with boost (which several applications use) and a cool shell. It also comes with `git`, which can be super useful if you want to compile files hosted on Github or other Git version control repositories without having to separately download the source.
   - Run the following commands in `cmd` or `powershell`:

     - `cd c:\sources\hello`: Change the directory to wherever it is that the source file(s) is/are located.
     - `g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe`: here `helloworld.cpp` is the name of the main source file, and `helloworld.exe` is the name of the compiled executable.
     - In case you have to compile multiple files list them before the `-o` switch: `g++ helloworld.cpp foo.cpp -o helloworld.exe`
     - These are the instructions for C++. If you're dealing with applications programmed in C, the file extension will be `.c` instead of `.cpp`, and you should use the `gcc` command instead of `g++`. The rest is more or less identical
     - *Note that you may need to specify more command line arguments in order to compile an executable which works properly.* The project page will usually have these details.
     - You also <strike>probably</strike> definitely want to look into makefiles. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481269/how-to-make-a-simple-c-makefile#2481326) Stack Overflow post is about makefiles in general, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873884/how-do-i-run-configure-with-mingw) tells us how to use them with MinGW. ***If a project comes with a makefile, try it before manually compiling the source.***
     - You should now be able to run `helloworld.exe`.
   - *Note:* Most projects come with a README file. Please do what the name implies, these files contain important information regarding compiling and running software and by reading it you can avoid a lot of unnecessary hassle.

<sup>1</sup>Note: Sometimes there may be a folder called `bin` among the downloaded files, which should contain usable executables/binaries

Also see [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com) and [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) if you want GNU/Linux command line utilities on Windows. I make some the latest version of some useful executables available for download [here](https://rahul.tech/archive/?dir=executables).

*Further reading:*
http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW_for_First_Time_Users_HOWTO
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/index.html#dir
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873884/how-do-i-run-configure-with-mingw

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer, and I've changed it to be marked as the definitive one. (I'd earlier edited my question to make it clearer that this was what I was looking for, but for some reason BoundaryImposition edited it out.)

Comment: I don't think it satisfies Aibobot's bounty request, however, but that's between you and her/him.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander Glad to be of any help! I'll add more to the answer later... 
 Yep, I was chatting with JourneymanGeek (Aibobot), he's going to wait for a few days for new answers to surface.

Comment: This project might not have any, but note that most projects will probably have *dependencies*, which means that if you're going the compilation route, you may need to track down the libraries that the software depends on, download them, and install them (or compile them as well). It's usually not as simple as just running the makefile; some of them may even have other build scripts such as cmake, configure script, etc.

Comment: Is the process really that simple in most cases? Which fraction of github utilities requires substantially greater knowledge to compile them than this what You’ve described here?

Comment: @gaazkam Most do. However, information and instructions regarding that are readily available on the interwebs. These are just the basics of compiling if your have no experience with the programming language, and are a starting point for the user.

Comment: @gaazkam> Depends on project complexity: does it have optional features that can be disabled, does it support several OS, … Small to medium-sized tools with proficient programmers usually compile easily without much knowledge. And if you get errors in the process, devs usually answer tickets pretty quickly in my experience. Just be sure to follow the instructions given on project's README first, most of the time they get the job done.

Comment: I think trying the Makefile should have highest priority, especially before trying to compile random source files.

Answer (score 87):

You look around and find the installer on the [release page](https://github.com/renatosilva/winutils/releases). Sure you could compile the source, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Agreed. If you have to ask, you don't want to be compiling from source.

Comment: If you have to ask, you probably *shouldn't* be installing software that's only available in source form...

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @jpaugh. While it's very possible and sometimes necessary to build from source, it's not something that you can just go and ask "how do I build a C program" in a generic way. There's just too much variance. Some lucky programs are as simple as "compile these files". Others need makefiles. Some need dependencies to be downloaded first. The process of setting up for build can be complicated and isn't necessarily non-programmer friendly. Above all, though, you want to find a file in the project that explains how to build, because specifics are project dependent.

Comment: @Kat Actually, I meant that it increases your chance of installing malware... assuming you actually manage to overcome all of the above. Of course, experimentation *is* the best way to learn... it just puts your computer at risk in the process.

Comment: @jpaugh - I'd say you have a much better chance of installing malware by downloading an executable - malware is rarely open-source.

Comment: Also if it is malware, it's easier to tell that it is when you have the source.  Assuming your compiler is not a confederate.

Comment: Assuming you can actually read the language. I semi routinely compile stuff on linux and I can't/don't read any of the source. Even if i could, I'm not going to review every.single.line.

Comment: The safety afforded by open-source is that not necessarily that *you* will read the source, but rather that certainly *someone* will, and that if there *were* malware, that someone would probably publicise it. The bystander effect here is mitigated by the fact that it's possible to publicise it entirely anonymously.

Answer (score 66):

.c and .h files are C source code.

You will need to install a C compiler such as Visual Studio, tcc or something similar, load the project and then compile it to run it.

Failing that, the project has a release page ([here](https://github.com/renatosilva/winutils/releases)) that will give you access to a pre-compiled version to save you time and effort.

Comment: If he had to compile it then it'd usually be explained in a readme, which you don't even mention he should look for.  He is meant to go to the release page, it's not just "failing that(installing a compiler), that he should go to the release page"

Comment: mingw is also popular.

Comment: A specific project is usually tailored for use with a specific set of compilation tools (called a "toolchain") - which one it is is normally mentioned in a readme file (in UNIX and cross-platform projects, it's conventionally named BUILD or INSTALL). In less than stellarly maintained projects, or projects for environments with only a few well-known toolchains, a user is supposed to guess from the format and/or content of project files.

Comment: TCC? Really? You weren't serious, were you?

Answer (score 18):

<sup>*This answer will be addressing the general question of building a source-only Windows application (in C). If you're lucky like the OP, you might be able to find precompiled binaries.*</sup>

The first thing to be aware of here is that there's no single way to build an app from source. There are approximately as many variations as there are different projects. That said, here are some general steps:

1. If you're lucky, the project will provide build instructions, usually within the `README` file. Occasionally, there might also be an `INSTALL` file, or other documentation available. If those are available, follow the instructions. They're your best bet.

   As others have said, unfortunately, it's very difficult to reconstruct the required build steps without instructions. However, we can at least make a best-effort attempt here, which will work for most simple projects.
2. Lacking instructions, the next port of call is to check which build tool is required.

   1. If you find a file with a `.sln` or `.vcxproj` extension, this is probably a MSBuild/Visual Studio project. Download a copy of [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.com/) or Express (for C++), open that project file in there, and click the play button in the toolbar (or use the build menu).
   2. If you find a `Makefile`, this is probably going to require `make`. But this is where things get even more difficult, since there's so many independent and incompatible systems that use `make`.

      1. Since it's targeted towards Windows, it's probably going to use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Download a copy of that, launch MSYS from your start menu, navigate (`cd`) to the directory that contains your project, and run `make`.
      2. On the rare occasion that it's Cygwin instead (there's no easy way to tell, unfortunately, but if the MinGW build errors out with a "posix"-related error, this is a decent bet), you'll have to install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) instead. Unfortunately, this does not build native Windows binaries -- you'll have to launch the program through Cygwin every time.
   3. The "build tool" could be a custom script by the name of `build.bat` or similar. In this case, you'll have to either open it up and see what's inside, or try running it and see what the errors are. If you open it and see mentions of `GCC`, go back up to the 2.2.1. MinGW step but run the custom script instead of `make`.
3. It's possible that there's no build tool at all. If all you encounter is a single `.c` or `.cpp` file, then it's probably simple enough that you can do a straight compile. These are, again, almost always [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), so download that, launch the MSYS shell, navigate to the directory, and invoke either `gcc` or `g++` as necessary -- e.g. `gcc -o program.exe program.c`
4. It's possible that none of these work. If you got error messages at any step, they might contain a clue of what's missing. One possibility is that you were lacking certain required frameworks or libraries -- if you feel up to it, you can try downloading those and adding them to your build environment, but this is typically not a trivial process and has so many variations there is no way to cover them in an answer.

---

## Glossary

### Build tools

A [*build tool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) allows you to build a project with very few commands. For most projects with more than a single source file, a build tool will be involved somewhere. There are several build tools, but the most common are:

- [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), used everywhere on Linux and increasingly common on Windows. Projects using `make` can usually be identified by the presence of a **`Makefile`**.
- [MSBuild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) is Windows-specific and is typically seen in conjunction with Visual Studio. These will usually be accompanied by a **`*.sln`** or **`*.vcxproj`** file.

### Toolchains

A [*toolchain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain) is the compiler and supporting tools. Just like the build tools, there are several, and they're usually used with one of the build tools.

- [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) is Microsoft's toolchain. This is the most common toolchain for Windows native development. This is usually used with the MSBuild system, and builds are usually created through Visual Studio. However, modern MSVC projects *can* use `Makefile` too.
- [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) ([MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)) is a port of GCC for Windows. Usually used with `make`. If the project is targeted towards Windows natively and has a `Makefile`, it's probably for MinGW-GCC.
- [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) ([Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)) creates a POSIX-compatible environment. This allows you to directly compile most programs written for Linux or Unix and have it work directly under Windows. <sup>More recently in Windows 10, [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/commandline/wsl/about) is an alternative.</sup> GCC is usually used in conjunction with `make`.

### Frameworks and libraries

[*Libraries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) are reusable sets of code written by other people, that many programs depend on to avoid reinventing the wheel. You need to have these dependencies available in order to build the project. If you're lucky, they'll be included with your initial download, but this is not always the case.

[*Frameworks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) are effectively a collection of libraries. Many projects use one framework, which you'll also need. These often come with their own build system too, but listing them all would be impossible.

The hardest part is dealing with extra framework and library dependencies. If, say, the project uses [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) -- then you'll need that whole mess to build it properly. This is a huge undertaking, and unless you have prior experience it's probably better to just ask others for direct help here.

Comment: In this *particular* case the makefile gives you a good clue that it is for mingw as the first line is `MINGW_PREFIX = $(shell which gcc | awk -F/bin/ '{ printf $$1 }')` :)

Comment: this one deserves the bounty imo